# How to Convert Extjs Datepicker to Hijri date picker

Tags: extjs, extjs3, hijri, umalquracalendar

i am developing an application using Extjs V 3.0,
i am stuck with Hijri calender picker, is there any way to use hjri calender in Extjs application? 
like we have already in Jquery [http://keith-wood.name/]

Comment: have u found any hijri calender in extjs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like any version of Extjs do not support Hirji Calender.
You need to use the external JS to display this calender